# Lock single pivot page

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have a pivot control with two pivot pages. I'd like to lock the first one on startup, so that the second page only appears on a special action.

As far as I know, only the pivot control itself is lockable, not each seperate page.

I wrote the XAML like this:

```
<toolkit:LockablePivot x:Name="Latinum" Title="pivotControl">
            <controls:PivotItem x:Name="PivotStart" Header="Start"     
                 Margin="24,28,24,27">
                <Grid>

                </Grid>
            </controls:PivotItem>
            <controls:PivotItem x:Name="PivotLauncher" Header="Launcher">
                <Grid/>
            </controls:PivotItem>
        </toolkit:LockablePivot>
```

and `PivotStart` should be locked at startup.
But only `pivotControl` has the isLocked property.

Answer (score 4):

You can't lock controls:PivotItem controls. Only the entire LockablePivot item is lockable to prevent changing the current panorama.

Regarding second appearing if you want just to show the second page you can set Visibility = Visibility.Visible and unlock the Lockable pivot.
But I'm not sure is it possible to change the active pivotItem from the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the second page appears after a button click or something similar you can do this:

```
Latinum.isHitVisible = false;


private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Latinum.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

So if user clicks the button, you set the selected item(which was `PivotStart` with help of SelectedIndex)  to `PivotLauncher`. You can use this in another event; like image tapped etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to lock the pivot you can use:

```
Pivt_control_name.IsLocked = true;
```

and unlock it by setting it to false;